# Update document doesn't work after driver update

Tags: mongodb, go

Everything works fine until

```
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver v1.4.0-rc0
```

but wont work starting with

```
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver v1.4.0
```

and above.

Since v1.4.0 Collection.BulkWrite() panics with following error:

```
panic: update document must contain key beginning with '$'
```

This is the method handling the inserts/updates:

```
func (db *DB) BulkUpsertDataModel(ctx context.Context, documents []*dbmodel.DataModel) error {
    var models []mongo.WriteModel
    for _, value := range documents {
        if value.Id == primitive.NilObjectID {
            models = append(models, mongo.NewInsertOneModel().SetDocument(value))
        } else {
            var updateModel = mongo.NewUpdateOneModel()
            updateModel.SetFilter(bson.M{"_id": value.Id})
            updateModel.SetUpdate(value)
            models = append(models, updateModel)
        }
    }

    _, err := db.Collection(Collection).BulkWrite(ctx, models)

    return err
}
```

The id of the DataModel is

```
    Id                      primitive.ObjectID  `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
```

What is wrong with the code? It's really strange for me, since it had worked pretty long.

Comment: Determine the query you are sending, compare to official *server* documentation for updates. You need to have operators in the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help.
The solution is

```
    updateModel.SetUpdate(bson.D{
            {"$set", value},
        })
```